# How to target form text label?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to target the text label in wpcf7 using css.
I've managed to target other elements using `wpcf7-form-control` but can't seem to target text.

HTML:

```
<div class="entry-content">
<div role="form" 
class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7- 
f337-p187-o1" lang="en-US" 
dir="ltr">
<div class="screen-reader. 
response"></div>
<form 
action="/contact/#wpcf7- 
f337-p187-o1" method="post" 
class="wpcf7-form" 
novalidate="novalidate">
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" 
name="_wpcf7" value="337" />
<input type="hidden" 
name="_wpcf7_version" 
value="5.1.3" />
<input type="hidden" 
name="_wpcf7_locale" 
value="en_US" />
<input type="hidden" 
name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" 
value="wpcf7-f337-p187-o1" 
/><input type="hidden" 
name="_wpcf7_container_post" 
value="187" />
</div>
<p><label> Your Name 
(required)<br />
<span class="wpcf7-form. 
control-wrap your-name">. 
<input type="text" 
name="your-name" value="" 
size="40" class="wpcf7-form. 
control wpcf7-text wpcf7- 
validates-as-required" aria- 
required="true" aria- 
invalid="false" /></span> 
</label></p>
<p><label> Your Email 
(required)<br />
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) 
{.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7- 
text{color: red;}}
```

And

```
@media (min-width: 768px) 
{label.wpcf7-form-control {color: 
red;}}
```

Nothing.

Comment: `class="wpcf7-form. 
control wpcf7-text wpcf7- 
validates-as-required"`
- If this is what you are trying to target then it looks broken as the is a `.` inside your class. 

`@media (min-width: 768px) 
{.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7- 
text{color: red;}}` - this might work if you fix the dot in the html and also remove this class as i dont think it exists just now `.wpcf7-form-control`

Comment: Dot in html just typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is no class with label name `.wpcf7-form-control` its his parent class you are targeting it wrong.

Try this instead

```
 .wpcf7-form  label{
      color: red !important;
    }
```

Comment: That does work, thanks, but is there some kind of specificity here as, when I try to move the text right, it moves the whole form right instead of just the label?

Comment: Yeah you can just write 'text-align:right;' on label css only which i provided you it will only move label text to right if not use 'display:block;' property also.

Comment: Thanks but I want to move by `x` px? Eg `margin-left: 40px;`

Comment: I am getting it right you want to move label text to right a little bit, then give it 'padding-left: 32px' whatever px you want.

Comment: Yes you can i repeat if margin or padding not working change its display property like 'block' 'inline-block' etc

Comment: Yes. Label to right. Inline-block and text-align right will align text but not move it right by specific number of px.

Comment: You mean`. Wpcf7-form label {display: block; margin-right: 40px;} `? That will select label and make it move right 40px?

Comment: no .Wpcf7-form label {display: block; margin-left: 40px;} this will make space to left so that it moves to right

Answer (score 0):

Your question is simple but you have some issue on your template, you are trying to refer to a label but you didn't give it a class or something to refer on CSS

Your template was also missing of some closing tab

give it a try:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f337-p187-o1" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
        <div class="screen-reader response"></div>
        <form action="/contact/#wpcf7-f337-p187-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div style="display: none;">
                <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="337" />
                <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="5.1.3" />
                <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US" />
                <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f337-p187-o1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="187" />
            </div>
            <p>
                <label class="input-label"> Your Name (required)<br />
                    <span class="wpcf7-form control-wrap your-name">
                        <input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" />
                    </span> 
                </label>
           </p>
           <p>
               <label class="input-label"> Your Email (required)<br />
               </label>
           </p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {

   .input-label{
      color: red;
   }
}
```

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7f4djw1z/).

before testing do not forget to enlarge your browser to a resolution bigger than `768px` to make the media query take effect

Comment: Doesn't work........ No specificity perhaps. That's just targeting `input label` not wpfc7 input label

Comment: Have you tried the fiddle?? Have you tried it with resolution lower than 768px as your media query establishes?

Comment: It doesn't change the text color to red

Comment: My media query establishes resolution higher than 768px. `min-width 768px`. Yes tried. Nothing.

Comment: I updated the fiddle, it words indeed, you just have to make the "result" frame (lower, right) bigger than 768px :)

Comment: for some reason I thought your query was "max-width"

Comment: Thanks but the fiddle doesn't work.`.input-label` doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry to bother but the fiddle work indeed (new updated link), the "result" frame, the one in the bottom-right corner is loaded as an iFrame so it's your window: you just have to enlarge it (dragging the middle divider to the left) and you will see that as soon as the frame reach 769px the labels became red as you need

Comment: I dunno. It doesn't work on my site when I try input-label

Comment: Did you managed to make it work by the fiddle? can you link me to the site so i can inspect it?